# Making an IOCTL for transmission of packets using "usb_bulk_msg" to the USB endpoint

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, usb, linux-device-driver

I have an application that sends 8000 audio packets per second. Now initially for experimenting purpose I am preparing a buffer of 8 audio packets and then making an IOCTL call and passing the buffer to my driver.

I am using "USB analyser". From the USB analyser I got that the inter packet gap(IPG) is around 20-40 usec. That is fine. But sometimes the IPG shows 200-300usec. Is it the USB subsystem(USB core/HCD) that is playing the role or the implementation of ioctl ?. Making >1000 ioctl calls and "copy_from_user"per second may be the culprit behind the late submission of packets. And moreover i am using USB3.0 which is capable of supporting 5 GBps data rate.

The code flow in my driver is like :

switch(cmd)
{

```
       case SEND_AUDIO:

                   copy_from_user(...,....,...); 
                   for(i=0; i<8; i++);
                   usb_bulk_msg();
                   break;
```

}

Comment: How big is an 'audio packet'?

Comment: Bulk transfers have no timing guarantees. How do you synchronize with the device?

Comment: Size of Audio Packet is 112 bytes.

Comment: Yes thats true that Bulk Transfers has no timing guarantees and instead we should have gone for isochronous transfer but the USB device that has been designed forces us to choose bulk transfer :(. But still as no other transfers are happening and with absolute BW available, bulk transfer should work fine. And for 1722 packet streaming we have to maintain IPG of 125usec. But it was failing to maintain that IPG so I thought may be USB subsystem is failing to submit packets on time and analyzer just showed that.